# Subtle type error

Tags: types, f#

I am new to programming and F# is my first .NET language.

I am attempting [this problem](http://rosalind.info/problems/dna/) on Rosalind.info. Basically, given a DNA string, I am supposed to return four integers counting the respective number of times that the symbols 'A', 'C', 'G', and 'T' occur in the string.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
open System.IO
open System

type DNANucleobases = {A: int; C: int; G: int; T: int}

let initialLetterCount = {A = 0; C = 0; G = 0; T = 0}

let countEachNucleobase (accumulator: DNANucleobases)(dnaString: string) =
    let dnaCharArray = dnaString.ToCharArray()
    dnaCharArray
    |> Array.map (fun eachLetter -> match eachLetter with
                                    | 'A' -> {accumulator with A = accumulator.A + 1}
                                    | 'C' -> {accumulator with C = accumulator.C + 1}
                                    | 'G' -> {accumulator with G = accumulator.G + 1}
                                    | 'T' -> {accumulator with T = accumulator.T + 1}
                                    | _ -> accumulator)

let readDataset (filePath: string) =
    let datasetArray = File.ReadAllLines filePath 
    String.Join("", datasetArray)

let dataset = readDataset @"C:\Users\Unnamed\Desktop\Documents\Throwaway Documents\rosalind_dna.txt"
Seq.fold countEachNucleobase initialLetterCount dataset
```

However, I received the following error message:

> CountingDNANucleotides.fsx(23,10): error FS0001: Type mismatch.
>   Expecting a
>       DNANucleobases -> string -> DNANucleobases     but given a
>       DNANucleobases -> string -> DNANucleobases []     The type 'DNANucleobases' does not match the type 'DNANucleobases []'

What went wrong? What changes should I make to correct my mistake?

Comment: I think your `Array.map` should be `array.iter` and you need to return accumulator

Comment: You have to `fold` the `dnaCharArray` array, as `countEachNucleobase` expects an accumulated value of `DNANucleobases`, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countEachNucleobase` returns an *array of* the accumulator type instead of just the accumulator it got as its first parameter. Therefore, `Seq.fold` can't find a valid solution for its `'State` parameter: it's just the record on the input, but an array on the output. The function used for folding must have the accumulator type as both its first input and its output.

In place of `Array.map` in the question's code, you could already use `Array.fold`:

```
let countEachNucleobase (accumulator: DNANucleobases) (dnaString: string) =
    let dnaCharArray = dnaString.ToCharArray()
    dnaCharArray
    |> Array.fold (fun (accumulator : DNANucleobases) eachLetter ->
        match eachLetter with
        | 'A' -> {accumulator with A = accumulator.A + 1}
        | 'C' -> {accumulator with C = accumulator.C + 1}
        | 'G' -> {accumulator with G = accumulator.G + 1}
        | 'T' -> {accumulator with T = accumulator.T + 1}
        | _ -> accumulator) accumulator
```

And then, the call in the last line becomes:

```
countEachNucleobase initialLetterCount dataset
```

---

**Shorter version**

```
let readChar accumulator = function
    | 'A' -> {accumulator with A = accumulator.A + 1}
    | 'C' -> {accumulator with C = accumulator.C + 1}
    | 'G' -> {accumulator with G = accumulator.G + 1}
    | 'T' -> {accumulator with T = accumulator.T + 1}
    | _ -> accumulator

let countEachNucleobase acc input = Seq.fold readChar acc input
```

Since strings are char sequences, `input` will take strings as well as char arrays or other char sequences.

Comment: Thanks, Vandroiy, for your reply. When I tried to use your Array.fold suggestion, I got an error message saying: 

"This expression was expected to have type
    char []    
but here has type
    DNANucleobases"

Comment: @MY_G That is strange. Are you sure you are using the code exactly as it is here, with both `countEachNucleobase` and the last line replaced? It runs fine when I try it in interactive.